# Do two random variables need to share the same domain or codomain or cardinality of their domain/co-domain when we add or multiply them?

Tags: functions, random-variables

Do two random variables need to share the same domain or codomain or cardinality of their domain/co-domain when we add or multiply them?

Comment: I think yes they should have the same domain and codomain. The codomain assumption is usually not a problem: one typically assumes random variables have codomain $\mathbb{R}$, in which case there is no problem defining addition and multiplication (e.g. $(XY)(\omega) = X(\omega) \cdot Y(\omega)$). It is important that they do share the same domain, however.

Comment: Why not define piecewise random variables when the two do not share domains?